# Java Logger - Netbeans hint "Inefficient use of string concatenation in logger"

Tags: java, netbeans, string-formatting

I am starting with java and I try log something.

```java
private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger("my"); 

String car = "bmw";
String dog = "dog"; 

_logger.info(car + " text " + dog); // on this line Netbeans
```

.. on this line Netbeans show me yellow bulb and say: *Inefficient use of string concatenation in logger*

So I click on "Convert string concatenation to a message template" and it change code to:

```java
_logger.log(Level.INFO, "[{0}] v{1} enabled", new Object[]{car, dog});
```

That cause problem. Because in log I see: `[{0}] v{1} enabled`
How to fix it?

Comment: Try `_logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("[{0}] v{1} enabled", new Object[]{car, dog}))`

Comment: @Ryan Amos: You should post that as an answer and something should be done about the title of the question

Comment: Are you using the Logger that comes with Java or a third party logging framework.  The code generated looks like it should work according to the Logger documentation, but I've never used Java's logging framework.

Comment: As @MichaelKrussel said -- what Formatter is being used? Can you upload your logging configuration?

Comment: Where do you see this problem?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790860/inefficient-use-of-string-concatenation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few options

1) Use String.format() `_logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("[%s] %s enabled", car, dog))`.

2) Use `StringBuilder.append()` or String.concat()`.

Ex: `_logger.log(Level.INFO, new StrinBuilder(car).append(" text ").append(dog));`

This is essentially what javac does in optimization.

3) Ignore the warning because efficiency is irrelevant for this. If you really cared about speed, you wouldn't be logging things. Logging takes a long time, and the difference between String formatting and String appending is very small relative to the time spent writing the log.

Comment: @user1571252 Try the new thing I put. I don't use String.format often.

Comment: There reason to use arguments instead of concatenation is to avoid the string creation if the log level is higher than INFO.  All of your suggestions will create the String every time.

Comment: The correct use for #1 is `String.format( "%s %s enabled", car, dog )`

Comment: @MichaelKrussel While this is true, I can't think of a single time when I have ever written something where logging was caused inefficiencies (although with C#, I have had the logger throwing an error and crashing the application)

Comment: Downvoted, because all of these perform string formatting and concatenation before determining whether the log message needs to be outputted.

Comment: -1 editing several times and yet not practically usable solution.

Comment: @RomanC How do you mean? All 3 of these solutions are both usable and practical.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga I see that you want to play the downvote game where you downvote everyone else's answer. I'd rather not play it.

Comment: @RyanAmos, I down-voted everything that basically said don't use the logging API and ignore performance warnings. Certainly, the logging APIs are not perfect, and IDEs can sometimes overzealously nag. But perhaps there's a reason for the API. And another reason why the output is wrong.

Comment: @RyanAmos Until you edited several times your post. You didn't understand `String.format`.

Comment: @RomanC Is it correct now? That's what matters. If it's not correct, let me know so I can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's just helping advice from Netbeans, actually code

```
_logger.info(car + " text " + dog); // on this line Netbeans
_logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0} text {1}", new Object[]{car, dog});
```

**produce the same output**. The first variant more coder friendly less time for typing debug messages, the second awesome.

Comment: The whole point of the parameterized API is to only concatenate if the string is actually needed. For example, imagine the logging is configured to only output `SEVERE` messages. Using the second API allows the framework to skip formatting. Parameterized messages are also the starting point of localizing log messages.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga What API do you talking?

Comment: `log(Level level, String msg, Object[] params)`. I agree it would be nice if there was a `info(String msg, Object[] params)`. If you are asking about localization, then I am talking about the `log*` methods that have `*rb` at the end, in particular `logrb(Level level, ..., Object[] params)`.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga this doesn't relate to my solution.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga Your arguments doesn't relate to the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

Any approach that generates the de-parameterized string before determining whether the message should be written *is* inefficient.

You probably have a poorly written `java.util.logging.Formatter`. By that, I mean a formatter that simply output's [`LogRecord.getMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getMessage%28%29) instead of incorporating [`LogRecord.getParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getParameters%28%29)

Comment: Nothing poorly written was made.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual formatting netbeans 7.1.2 do

```
public class Vels4j {

    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger("my");
    String car = "bmw";
    String dog = "dog";

    Vels4j() {
       // _logger.info(car + " text " + dog);
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0} text {1}", new Object[]{car, dog});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vels4j vels4j = new Vels4j(); 
    }
}
```

You can disable hints if you dont want. Also hint can be configurable.