# Does logging have significant overhead, even when it is OFF?

Tags: java, logging

I want to add detailed logging information using fine/finer/finest to my code to help me debugging my code. A nice thing (and maybe the whole point) of using logger instead of System.out.println() is that I can flexibly change the level of information that I want to see. Finally, once I am done with debugging, I can set my logging to OFF or SEVERE.

But I am concern, that even if I set my logging to OFF, the extensive use of logging messages, may impact the performance of my application at production time. Is it a point of concern? Or java logging is designed in a way that by setting logging level to OFF all overhead of logging is gone?

Note that even if we don't concatenate string for log message, we may still face performance overhead if we use it a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you're using a well known logging libs like log4j, slf4j etc - you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I am using Java own logging package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inefficient use of string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790860/inefficient-use-of-string-concatenation)

Comment: What do you mean with "Java own logging package"? Can you share an example of your code that logs something?

Comment: @MickMnemonic he's referring to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html

Comment: @MohammadRoohitavaf I'm not sure where your fear comes from. Does your application suffer from performance issues ? and even if the answer is "yes" what makes you think it's related to logging ? from my experience you have to try really hard (to do stupid things) in order to make logging affect your production (e.g. turn on DEBUG mode by default in prod etc).

Comment: @blafasel My question is not duplicate to that question. But there is a relation. Yes, if we concatenate string with + operator, the possible overhead my be higher. I am using MessageFormat class. 

But even if ignore that fact, and only use simple strings, still there my be overhead.

Comment: I think the answer is, you don't need to worry about this as it's really unlikely causing any significant performance problems in your application. The question would be more valuable if you shared a piece of real code that you think is affected by logging performance-wise.

Comment: Unless you can *prove* that this minor overhead is actually causing issues in prod... again, you have to do really dumb things in order to cause issues (like logging huge amount of data to fill the disk etc). If you're logging only things that make sense and keep it reasonable considering the logging levels - there's nothing to be worried about.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for half-cocked comment. But the other theme has a massive impact on yours. If you provoke other computation to build some string you can use to log you will have a big effect. If call your logger with simple arguments the JIT compiler will optimize any effect away.

Comment: @blafasel as I wrote twice already: there is no framework which is bullet-proof against stupidity... assuming *reasonable* usage, there's no need to be worried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no significant overhead.

You mention in a comment that you’re using Java SE’s logging package.  From the [java.util.logging.Logger documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html):

> On each logging call the Logger initially performs a cheap check of the request level (e.g., SEVERE or FINE) against the effective log level of the logger. If the request level is lower than the log level, the logging call returns immediately.

In other words, the log methods all return immediately if the level isn’t a loggable level.  The “overhead” of merely calling a method that returns so quickly would be measured in nanoseconds, if it’s measurable at all.

Unnecessary string concatenation, instead of proper parameterized logging, *can* create performance issues, but you already seem to be aware of that.  (I’m mentioning it for other readers who may not be aware of the issue.)

Comment: @alfasin That example discusses the difference in performance between string concatenation and java.util.Formatter.  That is entirely different from the fact that a Logger does not attempt any string formatting/concatenation whatsoever if the level is not loggable in the first place, for which reason it is far better to pass unformatted arguments to a logging method.

Comment: @alfasin The benchmarking results on that page support what I’m saying.  Parameterized logging is nearly twice as fast as string concatenation.  And he’s just logging int values;  imagine if he were logging Collections containing hundreds of elements.

Comment: @alfasin Quoting the page itself:  “The more operation per second, the better.”  Higher numbers indicate faster execution (more executions per second).

Answer (score -1):

A fine implementation of Logging is:

```
interface ILogger { void fine(String s); void finer(String s); void finest(String s); }
class Logger {
  public static ILogger logger;
  public static fine(String s){ logger.fine(s); }
  public static finer(String s){ logger.finer(s); }
  public static finest(String s){ logger.finest(s); }
}
class FineLogger implements ILogger {
  public fine(String s){ System.out.println(s); }
  public finer(String s){ }
  public finest(String s){ }
}
class FinerLogger implements ILogger {
  public fine(String s){ System.out.println(s); }
  public finer(String s){ System.out.println(s); }
  public finest(String s){ }
}
class FinestLogger implements ILogger {
  public fine(String s){ System.out.println(s); }
  public finer(String s){ System.out.println(s); }
  public finest(String s){ System.out.println(s); }
}
```

So in a configuration method you just set Logger.logger = new FinestLogger(); or other level and everywhere use Logger.fine/r/st methods.

To enable it by configuration you can read from a file.properties that contains such a line logger_level: fine on your main method.

```
main(String...args) {
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/project/mysystem.properties");
   switch(props.get("logger_level) {
      case "fine":
Logger.logger = new FineLogger(); break;
      case "finer":
Logger.logger = new FinerLogger(); break;
      case "finest":
Logger.logger = new FinestLogger(); break;
}
Logger.fine("Fine");
Logger.finer("Finer");
Logger.finest("Finest");
```

If you had fine as logger_level so only the world 'Fine' will be printed, the other ones will be ignored.

This way you completely avoid checking booleans values or enums or constants.

Notice that pattern can creates new implementations such FileLogger and etc..

Comment: I don't get it. How can flexibly change level in different time then?

Comment: You just need to set Logger.logger once, and use every ocurrence of Logger.fine and etc

Comment: I still don't get it. See, I want to add fine/finer/finest to my code. And then flexibility set in the config file that which level I want to show. At one time I like to see all, later I don't want to see none of them etc.

Comment: Alright, added some code so you can turn then on by properties.